# Angular this scope to be called outside

Tags: angularjs

If look into this plunker [Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ku4gTMJh0jlQAPUHcxYb?p=preview)

```
angular.module('testapp', [])
    .controller('testcontroller',function ($scope) {
        $scope.persons = [{ FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Doe' }, { FirstName: 'Peter', LastName: 'mal' }];

        $scope.onEdit = function ()
        {
            this.isInEditMode = true;
        }

        $scope.onCancel = function () {
            this.isInEditMode = false;
        }

        $scope.addnew = function ()
        {
            this.isInEditMode = false;
        }
    })
```

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Fname</th>
            <th>Lname</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="person.FirstName" ng-disabled="!isInEditMode" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="person.LastName" ng-disabled="!isInEditMode" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Edit" ng-click="onEdit()" /></td> 
            <td><input type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Cancel" ng-click="onCancel()" /></td> 
        </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addnew()"/>
</div>
```

I am handling
this.isInEditMode=true 
in edit button click and false in cancel button click.I am trying to Make isInEditMode=false on click of addnew.I am not able to do that can some body help how to handle this.If i create $scope.isInEditMode  it will enable/disable all rows which i don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add isInEditMode property to each person and them simply set all of them to false.

```
$scope.onCancel = function () {
  $scope.persons.forEach(function (person) {
    person.isInEditMode = false;
  });
}

$scope.addnew = function () {
  this.isInEditMode = false;

  $scope.onCancel();
}
```

I forked your plunker with solution:
https://plnkr.co/edit/pyBEuj79wIV2pcYRq2Lh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you put your variable in this, you should call it in the view as  follows:

```
angular.module('testapp', [])
    .controller(function testcontroller ($scope) {
          var vm = this;
        $scope.persons = [{ FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Doe' }, { FirstName: 'Peter', LastName: 'mal' }];

        $scope.onEdit = function ()
        {
            vm.isInEditMode = true;
        }

        $scope.onCancel = function () {
            vm.isInEditMode = false;
        }

        $scope.addnew = function ()
        {
            vm.isInEditMode = false;
        }
    })
```

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Fname</th>
            <th>Lname</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="person in persons">
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="person.FirstName" ng-disabled="!testcontroller.isInEditMode" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="person.LastName" ng-disabled="!testcontroller.isInEditMode" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Edit" ng-click="onEdit()" /></td> 
            <td><input type="button" class="btn-primary" value="Cancel" ng-click="onCancel()" /></td> 
        </tr>

    </table>
    <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addnew()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks.Thought it will work some reason it's not.if i use controller as syntax then all rows are becoming enabled/disabled.

Comment: I updated my answer, both syntax work.. function testcontroller ($scope)